# what maximum length of video can we record through HTML5 Media Recorder API?

Tags: web-applications, camera, video-streaming, html5-video, mediarecorder-api

What is the maximum length of video that i can record with a HTML5 Media Recorder API.

I have created a demo which record and save video on server in asp.net.
It is working fine for short video clip,but when size of video increases then bolb is not posted on Server why?

Comment: what error or warning does it give when you do so?

Comment: var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("blobContent", blob); var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("POST", prefixurl + "Recorder_uploader.aspx", true);request.send(formData);
    document.getElementById("Pmsg").innerHTML = "Please wait while uploading.....";i am not getting any response and also file is not being saved on file.